# TypeError in Python Programming

Tags: python

I wrote the following program for square each digit of a number. But, it is showing an error as "int" object is not iterable.

```
def square_digits(num):

a = 1
for i in num:
  a = i * i        
  return a

result = square_digits(12)
print(result)
```

Comment: Well, `int`s really aren't iterable... Can you give an example input and the output you'd want to receive for it?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `range(num)` function.

You probably also want to use a `list` (denoted by `[brackets, and, commas]`).

Try this for example:

```
my_list = [] # empty list
for char in 'aword':
    my_list.append(char * 2)
print(my_list)
```

Or to be really pythonic you can step through the data and create your list at the same time with a list comprehension. Think of it like an in-line `for` loop that returns a `list`:

```
result = [char * 2 for char in 'aword']
print(result)
```

The first part (`char * 2`) tells what you want in each entry of the list. In your case that would be a squaring operation on some source data. The second part (`for char in 'aword'`) tells you where to get the source data from. In your case it would be `range(num)`.

Answer (score 1):

first off, this is how to fix your code:

If you want a list of squared numbers beginning from 1 to num:

```
`
def square_digits(num):
    # initialize an empty list
    a = []
    # why num + 1 when you want numbers until num? check out this link for an explanation
    # on how to use and the different uses of the range() function
    # http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/
    for i in range(1, num + 1):
        # square the numbers beginning from 1,
        squared_i = i * i
        # and then add the result to the list that we have
        a.append(squared_i)
    # after everything is done, return the list
    return a

result = square_digits(12)
print(result)
`
```

In your earlier example, you were basically trying to make this work:

```
`
for i in 12:
    square_result = i * i
    print ("the square of " + str(i) + " is " + str(square_result))
`
```

which isn't going to work because you're trying to iterate on 12, which is an int

However if you do this:

```
`
for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]:
    square_result = i * i
    print ("the square of " + str(i) + " is " + str(square_result))
`
```

then you're going to have better results, because you're iterating on a list.

the shorter way of doing the above example is:

```
`
num = 12
for i in range(1, num + 1):
    square_result = i * i
    print ("the square of " + str(i) + " is " + str(square_result))
`
```

which should also work because `range(1, num + 1)` should return the list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]` if `num = 12`
in python2. In python3 however, the range function will not return a list, instead it will return something that can be iterated upon like a list for the purpose of this question.

However, I'm not certain if it's a list your looking for as a result, if not, feel free to clarify your question, hopefully others can also chime in.

Comment: Note that if he's using Python 3, as suggested by the parens in his `print` statement, `range` does not return a list but actually generates the range lazily.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I added some clarificatory notes to the answer to cover that fact.